# Generate text files

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with these lines:

```
Line 1:(load "c:/datafiles/07509/mkvas.lsp")
Line 2:getcells
Line 3:(vadwgs 1)
Line 4:QUIT
Line 5:Y
```

I would like to generate say, 10 text files(vadwg1.txt...vadwg10.txt), identical to this but with Line 3 changed to (vadwgs 2), (vadwgs 3) etc. Could I do this by a Windows batch file?

Comment: The answer is: *yes*; please change your post so that it constitutes a specific question that can be answered...

Comment: You should be more clear, how should the names be generated? In your first example line 3 is `(vadwgs 1)` but in your question you talk about line 2, which is correct?

Comment: Are you really still working with **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980's?? or are you actually using Windows command prompt?

Comment: Sorry - it should read "line 3".   Windows Command prompt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,10) DO (
>%%G.txt (
echo load "c:/datafiles/07509/mkvas.lsp"
echo getcells
echo ^(vadwgs %%G^)
echo QUIT
echo Y
)
)
```

The numbers in the for loop represent the first number, the step and last number, and can be changed if needed. So for a loop of 2 trough 11 you should use `FOR /L %%G IN (2,1,11)`.